# Strange behavior in Javascript new Date function

Tags: javascript

I tried to make Date object from string in javascript, but i see javascript parse date string very strange here.

```
> new Date("2012-01-01");
Sun Jan 01 2012 07:00:00 GMT+0700 (ICT)

> new Date("01-01-2012");
Sun Jan 01 2012 00:00:00 GMT+0700 (ICT)

> new Date("2012-01-01") == new Date("01-01-2012")
false
```

I use Chrome 32, as you can see they are 7 hour differ. Please tell me what happend here?

Comment: That. Is friggin. Weird. It's like the first one is returning the local time, the second UTC. Except it's adding in the GMT offset in there in both cases.

Comment: @remus It's *returning* local time in both cases because that's what toString does.  The first one is just getting *parsed* as UTC and the second getting parsed as local time.

Comment: You are relying on the Date constructor parsing a string, which is known to be inconsistently implemented by browsers in use. You can use a [string compliant with ES5](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15) but not all browsers support it. Better to manually parse the string and build the date object yourself.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's all about how the browser implements `Date.parse` ([spec](http://es5.github.io/#x15.9.4.2)).  That method is called on the string passed into the `Date` constructor ([spec](http://es5.github.io/#x15.9.3.2)) and first tries to match the string against a known format to determine what values are where.  I'd expect different browsers implemented that decision tree in slightly different ways, but Chrome's implementation probably assumes that the `"2012-01-01"` version is a prefix to the [ISO-8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard which is based on Zulu, or GMT/UTC, and includes a timezone (`"2012-01-01T00:00:00Z-07:00"`) while the `"01-01-2012"` version is a localization based on your LOCAL time zone, and doesn't bother to specify it (`"01-01-2012 00:00:00"`) so the 7 hour difference is based on the 7 hour offset between the ISO standard date and the localized date.  `Date.prototype.toString()` ([spec](http://es5.github.io/#x15.9.5.2)), by contrast, is supposed to display local time and is returned by the `Date` constructor, which is why it's localized in both return values from your test.

From the [spec](http://es5.github.io/#x15.9.4.2)  for `Date.parse`:

> The function first attempts to parse the format of the String according to the rules called out in Date Time String Format ([15.9.1.15](http://es5.github.io/#x15.9.1.15)). If the String does not conform to that format the function may fall back to any **implementation-specific heuristics or implementation-specific date formats. Unrecognizable Strings or dates containing illegal element values in the format String shall cause Date.parse to return NaN.**

Meaning if you don't use the full ISO-8601 date specified in [15.9.1.15](http://es5.github.io/#x15.9.1.15), the browser can make it up as it goes along or just give you `NaN`.  Even though this IS the standard, some browsers are notorious for not actually FOLLOWING standards, so you might consider just specifying all of the parameters unambiguously by parsing the data yourself and using the other `Date` constructor ([spec](http://es5.github.io/#x15.9.3.1)).

Comment: Excellent answer! I see this same phenomenon in Node.js as well. Looks like the best practice is to either specify your date structure or always default to YYYY-MM-DD.

Comment: That is the standard and has the added advantage of being sortable "alphabetically" as strings and ending up chronological as dates.  In case that's important to you...

Comment: @citizenslave—but "the standard" is not supported by all browsers in use so manual parsing is recommended, at least for the time being.

Answer (score 3):

The reason for the difference is explained in other answers. A good way to avoid the issue is to parse the string yoruself. If you want 2012-01-01 to be treated as UTC then:

```
function dateFromUTCString(s) {
  var s = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(Date.UTC(s[0], --s[1], s[2]));
}
```

If you want to treat it as a local date, then:

```
function dateFromString(s) {
  var s = s.split(/\D/);
  return new Date(s[0], --s[1], s[2]);
}
```