# Why does Javascript parse differently "2019-04-22" and "2019-4-22"?

Tags: javascript, datetime

The question is simple: why does javascript Datetime parser behaves inconsistently with almost the same input?

```js
console.log(new Date("2019-4-22"))
VM19018:1 Mon Apr 22 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)

console.log(new Date("2019-04-22"))
VM19021:1 Mon Apr 22 2019 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
```

The only difference between the two strings is that April is written as `04` instead of only the single digit `4`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strange behavior in Javascript new Date function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21152934/strange-behavior-in-javascript-new-date-function) (Yes the question uses different formats but I believe the answer is correct)

Comment: @NickA not quite a duplicate, but clearly a similar issue with the same underlying cause.

Comment: This really comes down to two things: 1) not using the language in the recommended way (use of dateString has been discouraged for years); 2) not using the required dateString format(s) (as demonstrated in this question) [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

Comment: @JohnColeman, I agree that this specific case is not covered, but this may be a candidate for merger or editing into the other post(both options are above my pay grade).

Comment: @Strom It is a judgement call. Duplicates are almost never *exactly* duplicates. I didn't vote to close this as a duplicate, but I certainly won't vote to reopen if it is closed.