# Weird behavior of `new Date` in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am not sure why it's working like this:

```js
new Date('2020-10-06')
// Mon Oct 05 2020 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) {}

new Date('2020-10-06 ')
// Tue Oct 06 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) {}
```

I want to get `new Date('2020-10-06')` as a `Date` object of the day(not previous day).

Could anyone give me an idea?

Comment: Time zone issue?

Comment: i dont think it's a timezone issue. in the above, i just added a space in the second example and it returns the correct day

Comment: @yash - It is, it's just a **really** non-obvious one. :-)

Comment: Not a direct duplicate but the reason is the same: [Strange behavior in Javascript new Date function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21152934) and [Javascript Date parsing behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54914638)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first example matches the [only format](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date-time-string-format) that the `Date` object is required to parse, and which has clear rules around how to parse, including whether to treat it as UTC or not (because it's date-only, the answer is: yes, treat it as UTC; [details here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date.parse)).

Your second example doesn't match that format (because `Date` doesn't `trim` the string), so it falls back on *"...implementation-specific heuristics or implementation-specific date formats."* In this case, it appears to treat the date as being in the local timezone, not UTC. But you couldn't rely on that cross-browser; another JavaScript engine might do something else.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. How can I make it to return its original date?

Comment: I don't want to add that extra space at the end

Comment: @yash - That depends. Is the "original date" expressed in UTC or the local timezone? If the "original date" is expressed in UTC, be sure to remove the spaces (and to be really sure, add a `Z` to tell `Date` expressly to use UTC when parsing it, because the spec on this moved around a bit unfortunately), then use `getUTCHours` and such when accessing the parts of the date. If it's local time, add a time part (like `T00`) so it's definitely interpreted as local time: `new Date("2020-10-06T00")` (that part of the spec didn't move around).

Comment: actually yes... it depends on timezone right. Thank you.